# What does the f do in plt.ylabel(f'g(x)')?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, f-string

Firstly,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
```

In an elementary example on how to plot with matplotlib in our lecture I encountered the following line

```
plt.ylabel(f'g(x)')
```

**What I have tried**

In the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel.html) there's no mention of an additional parameter to be inserted before the actual label text. I further checked out examples where `plt.ylabel` was used and discovered [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/usetex_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-usetex-demo-py) that also `r` seems to be a valid option.
Also, I discovered in [this example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/pyplots/pyplot_mathtext.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-pyplot-mathtext-py) that the "parameter" `r` can also be used in `plt.title`, but also in the corresponding [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.title.html) I didn't find anything.

**Entire Code**

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
X = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.2)
plt.plot(X,np.sin(X),'o-',label='$\sin(x)$')
plt.plot(X,np.cos(X),'*-',c='g', label='$\cos(x)$')
plt.ylabel(f'f(x)' rotation=0)
plt.grid() # adds grid 
_=plt.legend(loc=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Well, not really. In the case of `f'g(x)'` it is completely equivalent to `'g(x)'`. So probably someone just forgot to remove the `f` from some previous code. You can safely ignore the `f` and continue with your course.

Comment: @roganjosh I added the whole example, can you please explain what you mean by "whatever that function evaluation returns"? If the label would be $\sin(x)$ or $\cos(x)$, I would get what you are saying, but as it really only says f(x), I don't.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Ok, can you then explain its usage in the two examples I linked? Surely they don't contain a very similar typo, right? If I use ```plt.ylabel(r'f(x)')``` instead of ```plt.ylabel(f'f(x)')``` the labels looks the same.

Comment: As you can observe by removing the `f`, it does nothing.

Comment: @Alexander Please see my response to 'ImportanceOfBeingErnes'.

Comment: `f(x)` is the _name_ of the axis, as can be seen on the far left side of the chart.  Try `plt.ylabel(f'my label name', rotation=0)` and it becomes obvious.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik  [r-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals) are typically used to tell python you don't want the special interpretation of backslash. In matplotlib very often used when you want mathematical expression in latex format.

Comment: It does nothing =) I mean, it could be doing something if you had a string interpolation expression inside the string like print( f"The value of A is ${A}" ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the `f` in your code is probably a leftover from an **f-string**. You can read more on f-strings [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

As you mentioned, you can also find an `r` (or `R`) before a string. This defines a **raw string**. Raw strings are raw string literals that treat backslash (\) as a literal and not as an escape character.

Example:

```
dummy_str = "This is a \n normal string"
print(dummy_str)

raw_dummy_str = r"This is a \n raw string"
print(raw_dummy_str)
```

The above code will print out:

```
This is a
 normal string
This is a \n raw string
```

You can read more about raw string [here](https://knowledge.kitchen/Raw_strings_in_Python).

Answer (score 3):

f stands for format string
u can use it everywhere it is not 
matplotlib specific

example:

```
x = 12
print(f'Hello {x}') # That will print 'Hello 12'
```

Also:

```
print(f'Hello') # Also Works Just fine That will print 'Hello'
```

check if it is a left over f

Comment: No, you've made the same mistake as me. It can't be an `f-string`. The original example is missing `{}`

Comment: @roganjosh No it definitely is an f-string. It's just not formatting anything.

Comment: Fair. @SamyBencherif the answer doesn't really communicate that, though. It's likely a typo from the person delivering the course and it's just hidden by the fact that it ends up being valid syntax (python 3.6+)

Comment: @roganjosh This is the answer I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: I doubt it's a "typo". It's either an effort for "consistency" or maybe the author is new to Python and doesn't know exactly why it's there, they only put it there because they saw examples of other format strings.